# cURL POST request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl, post, google-api

I am trying to write the following `cURL` request:

```
$ curl -d @your_filename.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=ENTER-KEY"
```

In Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=ENTER-KEY",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function() {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("wrong");
        }
    });
```

This all came up together after stumbling through Stack overflow (all qns here were about posting login and pass). This request should send the information in `json` format to Google and the response should come, also in `json`. But nothing happens.
Should there something to be done to show the response? I thought ajax uses `XmlHttpRequest`, so it should work without any explicit task to show the response.

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Have you replaced the `your_filename` and `ENTER-KEY` values? Also, the response should be shown in the console of your browser (hit F12 in chrome/firefox)

Comment: Hey! Thank you, of course I did. And I looked up in a console, but there was nothing

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem as I did. You should use fetch() for such things it's really handy:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=YOUR_KEY';
var data = {some: json};
  fetch(url, {
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      'dataType': 'json',
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'follow'
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log(response.text());
  } else {
   throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
  }
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```